# ngx-loading not loading through service in angular 5

Tags: angular, loading

I am trying to create a loading effect whenever I hit my service for which I am using ngx-loading module.

In my component view I am adding this:

```
<div class="my-container">
   <ngx-loading [show]="loading" [config]="{ backdropBorderRadius: '14px' }"></ngx-loading>
 </div>
```

I can load this using this code inside my component.ts using:

```
   public loading = false;
    onSubmit(user) {
            this.loading = true;
     }
```

Here my code is working and it is loading fine but I have a service called svg service I am using this code:

```
onSubmit(user) {      
     this.SvgService.test();
     }
```

And in my service I am trying this:

```
  test() {
    this.loading = true;
   }
```

this is not working can how can I trigger loader from services.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Another option I just thought of would be to add a method in your component like so:

```
isLoading(): boolean {
    return this.SvgService.loading;
```

}

And then the HTML:

```
<div class="my-container">
   <ngx-loading [show]="isLoading" [config]="{ backdropBorderRadius: '14px' }"></ngx-loading>
 </div>
```

This gives the best of both worlds.

Original answer:

A basic solution would be to update your component's HTML to be:

```
<div class="my-container">
   <ngx-loading [show]="SvgService.loading" [config]="{ backdropBorderRadius: '14px' }"></ngx-loading>
 </div>
```

I generally **do not** support referencing a service from a component's template however. I would solve this by adding an rxjs/Subject to the `SvgService` and subscribe to it via you component.

In `SvGService`:

```
loading$: Observable<boolean>;
private loading: Subject<boolean>;

constructor() {
    this.loading = new Subject<boolean>();
    this.loading$ = this.loading.asObservable();
}

public updateLoading(loading: boolean): void {
    this.loading.next(loading);
}
```

And then use `this.updateLoading(true|false)` instead of `this.loading = true|false;`

In your component:

```
constructor(...) {
    this.SvgService.loading$.subscribe(loading => {
        this.loading = loading;
    });
}
```

With this method, you would still keep the property `loading` on your component and leave your HTML unchanged.

Comment: simon why I can't load from service

Comment: Typically, if you inject a service into a component it is 'private' and a private variable shouldn't be accessed anywhere except in the TS of the component. So, it's not recommended to make a service public and it's not recommended to use a private property (the service in this case) in the template. So that's why I suggest the alternative. You are, of course, free to reference the Service directly in the component's template if you really want, nothing will actually stop you.

Comment: Inside my component if I add public SvgService: SvgService this in constructor will my code work. I just want to make it very simple.

Comment: The code should work even if you leave it as private. Give it a try.

Comment: My code is not working that is why I asked this question. I am trying to load loader through my service. loading true works in component can I trigger loading through service.

Comment: you are still not getting what I am saying inside component I can load my loader using this I want to trigger loader from service.

Comment: So you're basically saying you want to use only the service and no HTML code in your component? If that was your question the whole time then the answer is no, that's not a thing. Not easily anyway.